# How to query from Cloud SQL with PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery, dataproc

I'm setting up a dataproc job to query some tables from BigQuery, but while I am able to retrieve data from BigQuery, using the same syntax does not work for retrieving data from an External Connection within my BigQuery project.

More specifically, I'm using the query below to retrieve event data from the analytics of my project:

```py
PROJECT = ... # my project name
NUMBER = ... # my project's analytics number
DATE = ... # day of the events in the format YYYYMMDD

analytics_table = spark.read \
    .format('com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery') \
    .option('table', f'{PROJECT}.analytics_{NUMBER}.events_{DATE}') \
    .load()
```

While the query above works perfectly, I am unable to query to an external connection of my project. I'd like to be able to do something like:

```py
DB_NAME = ... # my database name, considering that my Connection ID is
#  projects/<PROJECT_NAME>/locations/us-central1/connections/<DB_NAME> 

my_table = spark.read \
    .format('com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery') \
    .option('table', f'{PROJECT}.{DB_NAME}.my_table') \
    .load()
```

Or even like this:

```py
query = 'SELECT * FROM my_table'

my_table = spark.read \
    .format('com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery') \
    .option('query', query) \
    .load()
```

How can I retrieve this data?

Thanks in advance :)